# HTMLPurifier converts &pound; back to £

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm having a problem with the HTMLPurifier, which seem to be converting the

```
&pound;
```

back into

```
£
```

My current configuration is:

```
$config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank'));
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', true);
$config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);

$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'href*', 'URI');
$def->addAttribute('a', 'rel', 'CDATA');

$objPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$string = $objPurifier->purify($string);
```

First I was simply passing the £ symbol, which seem to be ignored and wasn't converted to `&pound;` so I've decided to run str_replace() before passing the $string to the purifier, but this was converting it back to £ symbol - so I'm really lost here and would appreciate some help if anyone knows what configuration setting might change that behaviour.

I'm now running the str_replace() after the purification, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design; the canonicalization that occurs here helps HTML Purifier avoid certain types of XSS bugs.  http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html is a worthwhile read.